# Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: d3.js

I try to implement a bar chart with D3, but it seems to give me an error like this:

> Error:  attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".

This is my code:

```
let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

let margin = {
  left: 80,
  right: 20,
  top: 20,
  bottom: 20
};

let w = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
let h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

d3.json(url).then((json) => {
  let data = json.data;
  let end = data.length - 1;
  let minDate = data[0][0];
  let maxDate = data[end][0];

  let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([margin.left, w])

  let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => {
      return d[1];
    })])
    .range([h, 0])

  let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(10, "");

  let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"), 5)

  let div = d3.select("body").append("div")

  let svg = d3.select("svg").attr('width', w).attr('height', h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      console.log(d[0].length)
      return xScale(new Date(d[0]))
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return (yScale(d[1]))
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return (h - (yScale(d[1])))
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
      return (Math.ceil(w / 274))
    })


})
```

Comment: use the `d3.timeParse()` to convert the date string to a Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. When creating your `xScale` you are passing strings not `Date` objects. Instead, you need to make `minDate` and `maxDate` instances of `Date`:

   ```
   let minDate = new Date(data[0][0]);
   let maxDate = new Date(data[end][0]);

   let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
     .domain([minDate, maxDate])
     .range([margin.left, w]);
   ```
2. You are not appending any SVG when doing:

   ```
   let div = d3.select("body").append("div")

   let svg = d3.select("svg").attr('width', w).attr('height', h);
   ```

   This appends a `<div>` on the first line and creates an empty selection on the second line as there is not yet—at least in the code you provided— any `<svg>` to select. You need to create an SVG and keep a reference to that selection:

   ```
   // Create a div.
   let div = d3.select("body").append("div")  

   // Append the SVG to the above created div and store the reference in svg.
   let svg = div.append("svg").attr('width', w).attr('height', h);
   ```

Have a look at the following demo:

```js
let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

let margin = {
  left: 80,
  right: 20,
  top: 20,
  bottom: 20
};

let w = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
let h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

d3.json(url).then((json) => {
  let data = json.data;
  let end = data.length - 1;
  let minDate = new Date(data[0][0]);
  let maxDate = new Date(data[end][0]);

  let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([minDate, maxDate])
    .range([margin.left, w])

  let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => {
      return d[1];
    })])
    .range([h, 0])

  let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(10, "");

  let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"), 5)

  let div = d3.select("body").append("div")

  let svg = div.append("svg").attr('width', w).attr('height', h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return xScale(new Date(d[0]))
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return (yScale(d[1]))
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return (h - (yScale(d[1])))
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
      return (Math.ceil(w / 274))
    })


})
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```